# Percent Variable from CSS ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, function, var

I'm trying to call `percentValue` from CSS `#number1` and have it run in the function in place of the absolute number which can usually be found after `"percent":`. I'm not really sure how it works and any help would be amazing.

```
(function($) {
    $(function() {
        var percentValue = document.getElementById('number1');
        /* thermometers with config */
        $('.thermometer').thermometer({
            percent: percentValue, 
            speed: 'slow'
        })
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Updated Code (Answered)

```
(function($) {
  $(function() {
           var percentValue = $('#number1').text()

    /* thermometers with config */
    $('.thermometer').thermometer({
      percent: percentValue,
      speed: 'slow'
    })
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: try document.getElementById('number1') **.value**

Comment: What type of element is `#number1`? You should select it via jQuery (`$('#number1')`) and use either `val()` or `text()` on it. Currently you're passing `percent` a DOMElement which isn't going to work. Also note the closure is redundant in this case.

Comment: Thanks Rory, I had done it in JQuery before and hadn't worked, now i see it was the redundant closure on the .text() that was messing it up. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var percentValue = document.getElementById('number1');`
Currently this code is selecting the **HTML element** not the **value it contains**

Assuming  number1 is a textbox or something, you can do:
`var percentValue = document.getElementById('number1').value;`
or (using jQuery):
`var percentValue = $("#number1").val();`